# How I get all brothers in 1 sql or 2?

Tags: php, mysql

How I get all brothers in 1 sql or 2?
which is more faster? which is good to my site ?
and how to do it in one sql ? can anyone write this sql for me ?

[image]

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `p`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `p`;
CREATE TABLE `p` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `categories_id` int(10) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of p
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('1', 'jimmy', '1');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('2', 'tina', '1');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('3', 'dd', '1');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('4', 'hello', '1');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('6', 'slucky', '1');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('7', 'asdf2', '223');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('8', 'sdaf3', '22');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('9', '2dfg', null);
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('12', 'asdf', '1');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('13', 'dsdf', null);
```

php code:

```
<?php 

    // get categories_id first
    $select_sql="select * from p where id = 3";
    $result=$db->execute($select_sql);
    $categories_id = $result->fields['categories_id'];

    // get all records has the same categories_id with id = 3
    $select_sql="select * from p where categories_id = ".$categories_id;
    $result=$db->execute($select_sql);

    // output all brother categories
    while(!$result->EOF){
        echo $result->fields['name'].'<br>';
        $result->MoveNext();
    }

?>
```

Comment: You have `id`, `name` and `categories_id` in your schema. What the hell are "brothers"?!? People in the same category?

Comment: Have you ever heard anything about sql injection?! And is it so hard to profile own code? Why the hell anybody should write code for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `p` main
LEFT JOIN `p` helper ON helper.categories_id = main.categories_id
WHERE main.id = 3
```

You can join the table to select the data. In *most* cases, as far as I know, joining a table is faster but Yogesh's answer is correct as well.

Answer (score 1):

The query will be

```
SELECT * FROM p WHERE categories_id IN (
     SELECT group_concat(categories_id) 
     FROM p 
     WHERE id = 3)
```

You have to use sub query to fetch the `categories_id` first and pass its result to upper query.

Answer (score 1):

Use left outer join!

```
select p.id, p.name, p.categories_id from p sql1 left outer join p on sql1.categories_id = p.categories_id where sql1.id = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think You will have any performance issues with 2 queries. 
But You can select information you need with one query.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (
    SELECT categories_id
    FROM p
    WHERE id = 3
) AS cat
LEFT JOIN p ON p.categories_id = cat.categories_id
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Which results:

```
+------+--------+---------------+
| id   | name   | categories_id |
+------+--------+---------------+
|    1 | jimmy  |             1 |
|    2 | tina   |             1 |
|    3 | dd     |             1 |
|    4 | hello  |             1 |
|    6 | slucky |             1 |
|   12 | asdf   |             1 |
+------+--------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will do it

```
 $select_sql="select * from p where categories_id = id and id=3";
 $result=$db->execute($select_sql);


 while(!$result->EOF){
            echo $result->fields['name'].'<br>';
            $result->MoveNext();
}
    ?>
```